# Placing all the code in an html file as opposed to separate html and css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have written the following code snippets to create a simple legend.

When I distribute them across HTML and CSS and JavaScript files, the webpage shows nothing, but when I stick them all in an HTML file, it works and I can see the three legend items.

I cannot figure out what kind of a silly mistake I am making that is leading to this behavior. Could someone please help me understand what am I missing or doing wrong?

**This one works**:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>D3 Legend</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

    <div id="legend"></div>

    <style>
        .legend {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .legend-item {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        .legend-color {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        const legendData = [
            { label: "Category 1", color: "red" },
            { label: "Category 2", color: "blue" },
            { label: "Category 3", color: "green" }
        ];

        const legend = d3.select("#legend")
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "legend");

        const legendItems = legend.selectAll("div")
            .data(legendData)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "legend-item");

        legendItems.html(d => `
    <span class="legend-color" style="background-color: ${d.color};"></span>
    <span class="legend-label">${d.label}</span>
  `);
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

---

**These 3 scripts together do not work**:

*HTML*

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>D3 Legend</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

    <script src="data-script.js"></script>

    <!-- Create an HTML element where the legend will be placed -->
    <div id="legend"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*CSS*

```
/* Create CSS classes for the legend and legend items */

.legend {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.legend-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.legend-color {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

*JavaScript*

```
// Create an array of objects representing the legend items. Each object should contain a label and a color.
const legendData = [
    { label: "Category 1", color: "red" },
    { label: "Category 2", color: "blue" },
    { label: "Category 3", color: "green" }
];

// Select the element where the legend will be placed and create a div with a class of "legend".
const legend = d3.select("#legend")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "legend");

// Select all div elements within the "legend" div (which doesn't exist yet), bind the legendData array to the selection, and create a new div for each item in the data that doesn't already exist.
const legendItems = legend.selectAll("div")
    .data(legendData)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "legend-item");

// Set the contents of each legend item to an HTML string that includes a color swatch and a label, using the data for each item in the array.
legendItems.html(d => `
    <span class="legend-color" style="background-color: ${d.color};"></span>
    <span class="legend-label">${d.label}</span>
`);
```

Comment: Those two approaches are not equivalent: in the second one you're calling the script  when the div still doesn't exist.